# Can I use the partial implicit differentiation with $x = e^xy$?

Tags: calculus

I want to know if I can use the partial implicit differentiation with this problem.

What is the derivative of $x = e^{xy}$?

Comment: I want the derivative wrt dy/dx

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering $y=f(x)$, you get:
$$(x)'_x=(e^{xy})'_x \Rightarrow \\
1=e^{xy}\cdot (y+xy')\Rightarrow \\
y'=\frac{1-ye^{xy}}{xe^{xy}}$$
Wolfram [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20x%3De%5Exy).

Alternatively:
$$ F(x,y)=x-e^{xy}=0\\
\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F_x}{F_y}=-\frac{1-ye^{xy}}{-xe^{xy}}=\frac{1-ye^{xy}}{xe^{xy}}$$

Comment: so when x or y as exponent, the x or y will move to front of the number? For example, this situation e^xy and put y and x in front of e^xy in numerator and denominator.

Comment: it is a chain rule. For example: $(e^{x^2})'=e^{x^2}\cdot (x^2)'=e^{x^2}\cdot (2x)$. It is the same principle when it is given $e^{xy}$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=xy$, then taking the derivative of both sides,
$$\frac{dx}{dx}=\frac{de^u}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$$
where the second expression follows by the chain rule. It follows
$$1=e^u\frac{d(xy)}{dx}$$

and using product rule,
$$1=e^{xy}\left(1\cdot y+x\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\implies 1=e^{xy}\left( y+xy'\right)$$

Solve for $y'$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do you know if I can use partial implicit differentiation with this problem?

Comment: If $y$ is the dependent variable and $x$ is the independent one, then there is no reason to use partial derivatives

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use partial derivatives, that is an option

$1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(e^{xy}) + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(e^{xy})\frac{dy}{dx}$

$1 = ye^{xy} + (xe^{xy})\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\frac {1-ye^{xy}}{xe^{xy}} = \frac{dy}{dx}\\
\frac {e^{-xy} -y}{x} = \frac{dy}{dx}\\
$

Comment: I think in your first equality, the second partial should be with respect to $y$

Comment: @Denis28 thanks

Comment: @DougM How can it be change to e^−xy−y / x from 1- ye^xy / xe^xy?

Comment: We have $\frac {1-ye^{xy}}{xe^{xy}}.$  Multiply numerator and denominator by $e^{-xy}$

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use implicit differentiation. You will get

$$\delta x = (x\delta y + y\delta x)e^{xy}.$$

(Here I've used $\delta x$ to indicate a variation in $x$, to clearly distinguish a variation $\delta$ in a variable from the differential operator $d$ on functions. But you might see $dx$ and $dy$ instead of $\delta x$ or $\delta y$ in your course notes or textbook.)

Now you can solve for $\delta y$ as a function of $\delta x$, away from $x=0$:

$$\delta y = \frac{e^{-xy} -y}{x} \delta x.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x=e^{xy}\to 1=(y+xy')e^{xy}$$ or by drawing $y'$ and rewriting,

$$y'=\frac{e^{-xy}-y}{x}=\frac{1-xy}{x^2}=\frac{1-\log x}{x^2}.$$

---

It is possible to check this by expliciting $y$,

$$y=\frac{\log x}x$$ which gives

$$y'=\frac{1-\log x}{x^2}.$$